# Apple Metal shading language - why does Apple recommend only having a single metal library

Tags: metal, metalkit

In [Apple's best practice documentation for compiling Metal shading language](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/FunctionsandLibraries.html), Apple recommends trying to combine all shaders into a single library:

> If you must use Metal’s command line utilities or runtime methods to
>   build your library, coalesce your Metal shading language source code
>   and group all your functions into a single library. Avoid creating
>   multiple libraries, if possible.

Why avoid creating multiple libraries? What's the problem in doing so?

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is that the Metal standard library is heavily-templated, so .metallibs contain instantiations of all of the templated types and functions referenced in your Metal code. Splitting your Metal code across libraries will cause some or all of those instantiations to be duplicated, resulting in larger binaries and slower back-end compilation.